# Creating a derived dict from a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a class derived from dict which looks like this

```
class Instance(dict):
    def __init__(self, space, vector, value):
        dict.__init__(self, space=space, vector=vector, value=value)
```

I will occasionally be creating dicts matching the 'schema' for this class, and I would like to just construct Instances out of those dicts for typing purposes. What is an elegant way to do this, without changing the existing constructor?

What I want to be able to do is something along the lines of

```
reconstructed = Instance(json.loads(data))
```

Comment: Please show us what that `__init__` actually does. And, more importantly, show us how you want to _call_ that constructor. Would a `@classmethod` alternate constructor work, like `Instance.fromdict(d)`? Or a keyword-only parameter like `Instance(fromdict=d)`? Or do you want some funky and brittle `range`-style constructor where you can call either `Instance(s, v, val)` or `instance(d)`? Or…?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to do? I find it hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Also, why is this a subclass of dict rather than either (a) a class that _has_ a dict rather than being one, or (b) just a function that returns a plain-old dict?

Comment: Its a subclass of dict for easy json serialisation. I'm basically looking for an constructor overload; I could make a classmethod that iterates over the dict filling the fields appropriately but was wondering if there's a nicer way

Comment: The common way to do this is to give a class an "alternative" constructor is to add a static method that accpets the calling sequence you'd like to use. i.e. `@staticmethod` on one line, then  `def from_schema(jsod_data):`, for the next one, then the code to do it. This method should return a new instance of the class and be called like this `an_instance = Instance.from_scheme(some_json_data)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know about elegance, but I needed to do that and I just created a function on the class like so:

```
def as_simple_dict(self):
    simple_dict = {}
    simple_dict['id'] = str(self.id)
    simple_dict['name'] = self.name
    simple_dict['attribute'] = self.attribute
    simple_dict['foo'] = self.foo
    simple_dict['bar'] = self.bar
```

And call it whenever I need it.

Hope it helps.